# Internet Explorer stay on the current page after clicking cancel button

Tags: javascript, jquery

On Internet Explorer, i am using below code

```
if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' || !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/) || navigator.userAgent.match(/rv:11/)) || (typeof $.browser !== "undefined" && $.browser.msie == 1)) {
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {

            //return "Ticket upload progress will be lost if you close/reload this window.\nDo you really want to continue?"
            var message = confirm("Ticket upload progress will be lost if you close/reload this window.\nDo you really want to continue?");
            if (message == true) {
                alert(1);
            }
            else if(message == false) {
                return;
            }
    }
}
```

When user click on **ok** or **cancel** in both the conditions, page is closed.

I want to stay on same page, if user clicked on cancel.
I have tried everything but not working.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Most (good) browsers won't let you do this for security reasons, to prevent sites making you stay on them when you try to close... (Spam pop-ups to make it impossible to close the site)

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
else if(message == false) {
    return;
}
```

with

```
else if(message === false) {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: After above change, I am getting Leave this page or Stay on this page message, actually i don't want any popup after that, i just want to stay on same page.